# Using an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have made a class called Artist - this class contains the artist name, DOB, genre and the CD Name, all of type String.

I have then made a main class that will allow the user to enter this information through the console at the bottom.

I am having two issues: firstly how can I allow the user to enter the information as type Artist into an array, and secondly, how can I then search the array to find a particular artist that has been entered? Not that all 4 variables (name dob genre and cd name) need to be stored in one element of the array. The array must have a max input of 40 artists.

Comment: It's unclear how far you've got with this... it sounds like `Artist[] artists = new Artist[40];` would be a good start. (I'd personally use a `List<Artist>` rather than an array, but maybe you'll be getting to that later...)

Comment: you can´t allow him to create a object of the type Artist for you, you need to logicly decide which information stands for the name and so on. After this you create an object intance with the parameters that the user did write into the console. 

For the second part you can either loop over the array by yourself, or override the equal method within the artist class.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
while (you_want_to_keep_enetering) { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String artistName = scan.nextLine();
    String dateOfBirth = scan.nextLine();
    String genreOfMusic = scan.nextLine();
    String cdName = scan.nextLine();
    arrayOfArtists[count] = new Artist(artistName,dateOfBirth,genreOfMusic,cdName);
    count++;
}
```

do something like this i think?